# Execute external command in split window

Tags: command-line, external-command, split

Is there a way to get the following in Vim:
If I execute a command in Vim like `!make c`, I would like to have a frame/split that pops up like in syntastic instead of switching to terminal view. That way, I would be able to go on writing or doing stuff in vim during compilation/command execution.

If I remember right, they added some asynchronous feature to vim (how ever it is used) so there is probably a plugin can fulfill my wish.

It would be also important, that when I execute another command I don't want to have a second window that pops up. It shall all be in the same window.

Comment: Thank you for editing, but I think that fulfil is also right, just not american English. Also I think that there need to be an that between "plugin" and "can fulfil" but I am not sure.

Comment: are you aware of tmux?

Comment: Yes, I am using it already

Comment: If I understand your question properly what you are looking for is being developped: Neovim already has a [`:terminal`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim_terminal_emulator.html) command which does what you want and Bram Moolenaar [started to implement](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/e4f25e4a8db2c8a8a71a4ba2a68540b3ab341e42) a similar feature in Vim 3 days ago. So you could have a look at [neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim) or wait to see how this feature will be implemented in Vim.

Comment: :term is now part of vim (even if it is still not finished) and it does what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use your shell in a split inside the vim session using this plugin :
[ConqueShell](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Conque-Shell)

Since this opens in a split view, it would not disturb your currently working area.

I have mapped it as such on my Windows machine :

`map cc :ConqueTermSplit cmd.exe<CR><CR>`

Note : `<CR>` has been written twice to avoid a warning message at startup that goes away after pressing Enter.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have tmux, why don't you just split the window and run the command in a new pane?

If you want to automate this with a Vim mapping take a look at [vim-tmux-runner](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-runner).

Comment: I tried to explain why - gone more and more into detail and noticed by explaining what exactly I am looking for it is nearly impossible to get - I am not opening a split because I have already splits and tabs and stuff open and max out splits with one vim instant pretty often

Comment: How about a [tmux split](http://lukaszwrobel.pl/blog/tmux-tutorial-split-terminal-windows-easily) on top of the currently split vim session?

Answer (score 1):

I use a `normal` command aliased to `Sh` and then place the command I want to run after it.

With this text in a sourced file (e.g. vimrc):

```
command! -nargs=* -complete=shellcmd ShellRead new | setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile | read !<args>
cabbrev Sh ShellRead
```

I then type:
`Sh !make c`
instead of using the `!` and the command runs and shows the output in a new window within vim.

It does consume the vim session, however, so mainly I use it for quick tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Stub: depending on the command, you may want to filter the buffer with `:[range]!` or use the vim 8 `:terminal`. The `new | 0read !command` is good too.